# Is it right that "One approach is A, B or C"

Tags: grammar

Sometimes, I am very confused about *and*, *or*. I wonder that I can use the following sentence:

> One approach is A, B or C.

I think the following is incorrect. (right?)

> One approach is A, B and C.

Instead, the following is fine. (right?)

> The possible approaches are A, B and C.

---

The context I want to use.

> There have been a number of approaches that propagate the initial state of the region of interest for obtaining its segmentation over time. One example is to apply split-and-merge scheme [29], dynamic programming [30], or track-64 ing [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what you want to know more clearly.  We have no idea whether A, B, and C are separate options or are considered one option.  (And likely neither does your reader.)  From that standpoint the third version is probably best, but only if that's what you mean (which, again, is unclear).

Comment: I added a sentence from my paper.

Comment: Isn't that three examples?

Comment: Is the "*one example*" one of the approaches, which itself involves 3 possible subapproaches? Or are those 3 of the approaches? If the latter, try "*These include*...*and*..." instead of "*One example is to apply*...*or*...".

Comment: There are 3 approaches, not subapproaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your first two examples is quite distinct. In the first you're suggesting that either A,B or C are an approach. That is any one of A, B and C could work. In the second example, you're suggesting that A,B and C are collectively a solution.

Example:

> One approach to getting to the top floor is to walk, use a jet-pack, or use an elevator.

Or:

> One approach to getting to the top floor is to open the door to the stairs, closing it behind you and walk to the top.

Hope this helps.